# 360 degree video support in ffmpeg HLS

Tags: nginx, ffmpeg, http-live-streaming, virtual-reality, 360-virtual-reality

I want to play 360 degree videos using HLS/DASH protocols. I am currently using ffmpeg and nginx combo. my question is does ffmpeg support 360 video transcoding to hls format. I tried with following command but 360 degree meta data is dropped by ffmpeg. is there any alternative way to do this?

```
ffmpeg  -i 360Videosample.mp4 \
-preset fast -g 25 -sc_threshold 0 \
-map v:0 -c:v:0 libx264 -b:v:0 2000k \
-map v:0 -c:v:1 libx264 -b:v:1 6000k \
-map a:0 -map a:0 -c:a aac -b:a 128k -ac 2 \
-f hls -hls_time 4 -hls_playlist_type event  \
-master_pl_name master.m3u8 \
-var_stream_map "v:0,a:0 v:1,a:1" stream_%v.m3u8
```

Comment: I'm not sure why you were downvoted - it would help if people added comments when doing that so you know what to update in your question. You may find one way is to add the metadata back in after conversion - see the Exiftool and the discussion here: https://superuser.com/questions/1208273/add-new-and-non-defined-metadata-to-a-mp4-file

Comment: thanks Mick for response. tools such as Exiftool, spatial metadata injector would not add metadata to .m3u8 files. They can add to traditional file types such as mp4 etc.

Comment: HLS actually can use fragmented mp4 files but this may not help you if you are losing the metadata in your encoding steps. Can you share exactly what metadata is being lost?

Comment: Following is the spatial metadata missing                                                                 
   Side data:
      spherical: equirectangular (0.000000/0.000000/0.000000)